# Testing Pinia store inside Nuxt3 with vitest throws `useRuntimeConfig` not defined

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3, pinia, vitest

I am testing pinia store in `nuxt3` app.

Inside `setup()` of store I'm using `useRuntimeConfig` to get initial value for counter from public config variables and I got this error `ReferenceError: useRuntimeConfig is not defined` don't know how to solve it

```
// store/counter.ts

...
state: () => {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
    const count = runtimeConfig.public.count
    return {
      ...
      count
      ...
    }
  },
...
```

code

```
// store/counter.test.ts

import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import { describe, expect, it, beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import { setActivePinia, createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { useCounter } from './counter'
import { setup } from '@nuxt/test-utils'

await setup({
  rootDir: fileURLToPath(new URL('../', import.meta.url)),
  server: true,
  browser: true,
})

describe('Counter Store', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // creates a fresh pinia and make it active so it's automatically picked
    // up by any useStore() call without having to pass it to it:
    // `useStore(pinia)`
    setActivePinia(createPinia())
  })

  it('increments', () => {
    const counter = useCounter()
    expect(counter.n).toBe(0)
    counter.increment()
    expect(counter.n).toBe(1)
  })

  it('increments by amount', () => {
    const counter = useCounter()
    counter.increment(10)
    expect(counter.n).toBe(10)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 9):

This looks similar to an issue that I just solved today. Hopefully it helps you too:

1. In your component, in this case the Pinia store module, add the explicit import for useRuntimeConfig, as below:

   `import { useRuntimeConfig } from '#imports'`

At the moment I don't have a better way to get around the package being 'undefined' aside from just manually importing it. As Nuxt3 progresses, I'm hoping to see testing become more a focus. **Documentation seems to suggest importing it from '#app' but I've not been able to get it working that way and '#imports' seemed the more appropriate alias.**

2. In your vitest.config.js, add in an alias that maps the `#imports` package to the hidden nuxt file. An example of a vitest.config.js file is below:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    // other test specific plugins
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
      '#imports': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts')
    }
  }
})
```

3. In your test file, use the vi.mock() function to mock the `#imports` package.

```js
 vi.mock('#imports', () => {
    return {
      useRuntimeConfig() {
        return {
          public: {
            // Your public config!
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

This allowed me to mock the runtimeConfig at a test level - hopefully it helps you too! Good luck :D

<s>For anybody reading this wanting to achieve a similar thing in Jest, [this is the GitHub discussion](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3374) that helped me figure this solution out.</s> Unfortunately the discussion I used to create this solution no longer exists. (404)

EDIT: If you need to change the mocked return value on a test-by-test basis, you can return an object defined elsewhere and change the values of that object in your test.

i.e.

```js
    let storeMock = {
       user: {
         getUsername: 'Jane Doe',
         setUsername: vi.fn()
       }
    }

    vi.mock('#imports', () => {
        return {
           useNuxtApp: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
               $store: {
                   ...storeMock
               }
           })),
        }
    })

    // In your test
    storeMock = {
        user: {
            getUsername: 'Janet Van Dyne',
            setUsername: vi.fn()
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this solution @katieAdamsDev, I was on the same subject, very hard to understand how to test components that have composables auto-import in them. ;) 
Could you add the github link you spoke about ?

Comment: @nodeover D'oh! What a dummy haha, I've linked to the GitHub discussion in my original post now :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I did not want to explicitly import the composables in the components.
There is a plugin that helped me a lot called ['unplugin-auto-import/vite'](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import).

With my vitest.conf.ts am able to mock my useRoute without importing it in the component explicitly.

*vitest.config.ts*

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  root: '.',
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      /* options */
      imports: ['vue-router'],
    }),
  ],

  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './setupTests.ts',
  },
  // ... standart nuxt resolve stuff from ./.nuxt/tsconfig.json
})
```

*VueComponent.vue*

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute()
defineProps<{
  componentName?: string
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ route.fullPath }}
  </div>
</template>
```

*your tests*

```
import VueComponent from '@/components/VueComponent.vue'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/vue'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { vi } from 'vitest'

describe('Default Content Component', () => {
  test('Renders Content', () => {
    render(VueComponent, {
      global: {
        mocks: {
          route: { fullPath: 'asds' },
        },
      },
    })
    // ... your assertions
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I used vitest `globalThis` as effectively the tests thought `useRuntimeConfig` was undefined I could set it in my test like this:

```
globalThis.useRuntimeConfig = () => {
  return {
    public: {
       something: 'value'
    },
  };
};
```

Sharing sentiments with @KatieAdamsDev, I hope that the auto importing with nuxt tests becomes a little easier. For the moment the above seems not necessarily the correct long-term solution, but I will wait for the Nuxt team to define what that is.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thank you very much!